# mutate_at is very slow

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with data that arise from an instrument that produces a spectrum. That means each data *point* is 3201 elements long. I want to normalise the data from time-to-time, either by subtracting the median or using `scale`. My data is in a tibble with other variables, therefore I thought I would use the `mutate_at` function from `dplyr`, however this seems to take an exceptionally long time.

```
set.seed(123)
## generate some test data
ncol = 100
d_f = data.frame(color = rep('C', 5), 
                 rep = factor(1:5), 
                 matrix(rnorm(5 * ncol), nrow = 5))
d_f = as.tibble(d_f)

sc1 = function(x, scale =  c("med", "z")){
  scale = match.arg(scale)

  if(scale == 'med'){
     x = x %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("^X[0-9]+$")), funs(. - median(.)))
  }else if(scale == 'z'){
    x = x %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("^X[0-9]+$")), funs(base::scale))
  }
}

sc2 = function(x, scale = c("med", "z")){

  scale = match.arg(scale)

  y = x %>% select(matches("^X[0-9]+$")) %>% as.matrix()

  if(scale == 'med'){
    y = sweep(y, 2, apply(y, 2, median))
  }else if(scale == 'z'){
    y = base::scale(y)
  }

  y = as.tibble(y)
  names(y) = paste0("X", 1:ncol)
  x = x %>% select(matches("^[^X].*$")) %>% bind_cols(y)
  return(x)
}

microbenchmark(d_f %>% sc1, d_f %>% sc2)
```

Here are the results with a 100 columns:

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  d_f %>% sc1 142.1663 157.08819 188.71257 174.88702 209.38378 441.79132   100   b
  d_f %>% sc2  12.6180  15.17256  18.83863  16.90944  20.11142  45.81297   100  a
```

And here are the results with just 10 columns:

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 d_f %>% sc1 13.904984 15.975898 19.38772 17.34842 21.25275 40.98175   100   b
 d_f %>% sc2  8.817058  9.746072 11.74869 10.89266 12.93568 23.96279   100  a
```

A single run with 3201 of `sc1` takes ~72 seconds, hence the reduced test sets.

Comment: The result of the two functions are not the same. And they don't seem to do the same thing to me. What are you comparing here?

Comment: You at least want `apply(y, 2, median)` to get the column medians, not the row medians. But my guess is that 90% of the difference is because it's just faster to work on a matrix than a data frame.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor - small mistake there and I have corrected it.

Comment: @Psidom - yes they do do the same thing now. The aim is explained above. I wish to standardise the rows, either by subtracting the column medians, or by subtracting the column mean and dividing by the column standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be that the overhead of `mutate_at()` is way bigger than converting from/to `matrix`.

Here is a profiling of `sc1()`:

```
> summaryRprof()$by.self
                          self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"FUN"                          0.34    19.54       0.92     52.87
"makeActiveBinding"            0.24    13.79       0.48     27.59
"lapply"                       0.20    11.49       0.88     50.57
"make_active_binding_fun"      0.20    11.49       0.24     13.79
"sort.int"                     0.14     8.05       0.14      8.05
"vapply"                       0.12     6.90       0.36     20.69
"%in%"                         0.04     2.30       0.14      8.05
"get_env"                      0.04     2.30       0.10      5.75
"rm"                           0.04     2.30       0.06      3.45
"!"                            0.04     2.30       0.04      2.30
"force"                        0.04     2.30       0.04      2.30
".Call"                        0.02     1.15       1.68     96.55
"tryCatch"                     0.02     1.15       1.66     95.40
"<Anonymous>"                  0.02     1.15       1.48     85.06
"%||%"                         0.02     1.15       0.08      4.60
"type_of"                      0.02     1.15       0.06      3.45
"is_null"                      0.02     1.15       0.04      2.30
"=="                           0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
"all"                          0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
"any"                          0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
"as.character"                 0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
"inherits"                     0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
"is_formulaish"                0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
"is.null"                      0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
"names"                        0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
"sys.call"                     0.02     1.15       0.02      1.15
```

Comment: I think this is exactly right, but to really make the point you should compare to the profile of `sc2()`.

Comment: I agree. I should have included that to really make the point (I did the profiling).

Comment: I did the profiling as well, but couldn't make head or tails of the output.